# What is the best way to create API app for Flutterflow app?

Tags: flutter, api, heroku, flutterflow

I'm trying to make an ios/android application on Flutterflow and am stuck when I need some API calls. Am I supposed to deploy a separate API app on Heroku and then integrate it with Flutterflow or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to relay to a Baas such as Firebase, Supabase..., then in order to exchange data to a third-party source, then yes, you will need to build your own REST API using some back-end laungage, framework..

After that, you will need to deploy it somewhere in the cloud, and yes like heroku or any other one based on your requirements.

And then you should have the base URL of it and use it to make API calls from your Flutter/FlutterFlow app.